# Node.js with express: Losing form data with if error found

Tags: node.js, forms, express

When I submit my form and an error is found (such as "age is missing"), the entire form data is wiped clean.

I just need to repopulate the already entered data for the user. Currently I'm trying to see if I can pull the data and pass it to the form data (as seen below). Any help would be awesome. Thanks so much.

Here is what I have:

Controller.js

```js
exports.createStore = async(req, res) => {
  var store = new Store(req.body);

  req.checkBody('age', 'Age cannot be blank').notEmpty();

  var errors = req.validationErrors();

  if (errors) {
    res.render('WebPage', {
      title: 'Webpage Title',
      errors: errors,
      formData: {
        age: req.body.age
      }
    });
  } else {
    //Do all the things
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you include the code for `checkBody`  and `validationErrors`? I suspect one of them is mutating body.

Comment: Well checkBody and validationErrors are both part of the express-validation package. So I don't want to change that code unless everything else fails.

Comment: I think you mean `express-validator`. Can you confirm if `req.body` is not empty after `checkBody` and `validationErrors` is called? Maybe logging it immediately after. That would prove whether or not it's being mutated. If it's not being mutated then I'd suspect a solution similar to @djheru's is required.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a template engine like pug or handlebars? If so, you will need to get the value of `formData.age` and assign it to the value in your html inputs something like

`<input name="age" type="text" value="<%= formData.age || '' %>" />`
if you are using the ejs template engine. Basically, you have to get the value from the `render` call and use it to set the value in the HTML

Comment: I am using PUG, so I will look into this. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sure, just remember, if an answer is helpful, you can always feel free to upvote or accept the answer.